# Нужна ли здесь запятая? ЕГЭ, очень переживаю

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение:

*На жизненном пути нам встречаются люди, которых, как нам кажется, можно сразу, не задумываясь, назвать глупыми или умными, бездарными или талантливыми.*

Правильно ли я поставил запятые? Нужна ли запятая после "задумываясь"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Да, пунктуация правильная.

Конкретно по запятой после "не задумываясь". Она настолько естественна, что даже не сразу вопрос понял.

Если ваши сомнения связаны с тем, не считать ли "сразу" и "не задумываясь" однородными членами, то это напрасно. ***Здесь "не задумываясь" достаточно очевидное уточнение для "сразу".*** Конечно, строго говоря, выбор тут за автором, но в рамках ЕГЭ это слишком большая вольность найти тут однородные члены.

Если сомнения на чем-то еще основываются, напишите конкретно.

Примеры из Нацкорпуса.

> Главное, объяснил он, прыгать сразу, не задумываясь, потому что любая
>   мысль, даже самая незначительная, может расслабить тело, которое
>   должно разогнуться, как пружина. [В. А. Каверин. Освещенные окна
>   (1974-1976)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→
>
> Юра ответил сразу, не задумываясь, и быстро, затравленно взглянул на 
>   товарища: [Л. Р. Кабо. Повесть о Борисе Беклешове (1962)] [омонимия
>   не снята] ←…→
>
> Как будто сел человек к столу и сразу, не задумываясь, написал письмо к
>   когда-то любимой женщине; даже трудно себе представить, как
>   же иначе, какими другими словами можно написать это. [В. В. Вересаев.
>   Что нужно для того, чтобы быть писателем? (1921)] [омонимия не снята]
>   ←…→

http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%F0%E0%E7%F3%2C+%ED%E5+%E7%E0%E4%F3%EC%FB%E2%E0%FF%F1%FC

Примеров без запятой не обнаружил.